# Does python perform tasks on lists in parallel by itself?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, parallel-processing

I stumbled upon this piece of work:

```
def getChild(self, childName):
    for child in self.children :
        if(childName == child.data['name']):
            return child
    return None
```

As far as ranting is concerned this code implies everything there is to say and know about this library.

I am not that deep into python but I afaik the canonic pythonic way of going about this task is

```
def getChild(self, childName):
    return (
        [ child for child in self.children
            if child.data['name'] == childName
        ] + [ None ]
        )[0]
```

or, for better readability,

```
def getChild(self, childName):
    myChildren = dict([
         (child.data['name'],child)
             for child in self.children
    ])
    try:
        return myChildren[childName]
    except:
        return None
```

Besides the fact that I still have no clue about how and when to indent and where to put `{`,`[`,`(`,`)`,`]` and `}`, my alternatives always operate on all elements of `self.children`.

Does python recognise this and work through the data sets in parallel, or will it still work through the array sequentially? (and therefore always take longer than the simple search I found in that library)

With the amount of lookups performed it is of course better to change the library to always maintain a dictionary of children instead of a list, but that is besides the point. I would like to know how python interprets and handles this code.

Comment: As a side note on code layout, you should check out [PEP 08 -- Style Guide for Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#code-lay-out).

Comment: The first code block is by far the best of the three (although the `return None` can be removed entirely).

Comment: And no, Python doesn't automatically parallelize anything. That is your job.

Comment: No. Python doesn't automatically parallelize anything; CPython also doesn't even let you run Python code in parallel within the same process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no automatic parallelization. Python is about writing your code efficiently, but not about making it computationally efficient. And there is a bigger problem: the GIL - Global Interpreter Lock. That means that only one thread at a time is executed. So there is no big point in parallelization of CPU intensive tasks in python. There are interpreters without GIL, but general rule of thumb: if you don't know about GIL, then you have it.

Concerning the code you've posted: python allows you to write in the most common procedural style or in functional style, beloved in universities. You can choose any.

Comment: Concerning the parallelism, GIL is the correct answere. One might add, that if you wan real concurrency in Python you either need to use a different Python implementation (Cython or PyPy) or you will have to utilize the 'multiprocessing' package

Comment: Why is python becoming ever more popular for simulations and "big data" if it behaves so poorly in terms of parallel processing. I will check out the multiprocessing package thoug, just to find out.

Comment: As rikisa has already answered, there are ways to overcome bottlenecks (by using interpreters that behave much better for multi-threaded applications, by using many processes instead of a thread, by using libraries written in C). In worst case, you always can rewrite business critical bottleneck in C++ if performance is critical.

Comment: But there is another reason too. There is application execution time (which is not great in python) and time needed to develop an application (which is python's strong point). You are always interested in their sum. When you are experimenting much (which is often a case in big data) you run the code only several times. It is just cheaper to pay for more CPU time than pay salary for more programmer time.

Comment: It's possible to do automatic parallelization using [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/parallel.html), but it only works with a small subset of Python.